# Prevent Firefox from adding text node to contentEditable div (Firefox bug?)

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, contenteditable, cursor-position

I have a contentEditable div element. On the first keypress in the editable area I create a container <p> tag using the following logic:

```
var c = (32 == key ? '\u00A0' : String.fromCharCode(key));
var e = document.createElement('p');
var sel, rng;
e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c));
this.editDocument.appendChild(e);
sel = window.getSelection();
rng = document.createRange();
rng.selectNodeContents(e);
rng.collapse(false);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(rng);
```

The problem I have is on the next keypress event Firefox creates another text node as the container for the new character as well as any subsequent characters. This means my p tag has 2 text nodes as siblings. Google Chrome and Opera don't do this. This extra text node creates an issue with my undo/redo system. This undo system saves the caret position as an array of node offsets. The contents of the contentEditable div are saved and restored using innerHTML. However when the contents are restored via this method only a single text node is created, where Firefox previously had 2, causing an error. I'm wondering if this behaviour (creating the extra text node) is intentional in Firefox, or if it perhaps a bug. Any suggestions or advice much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like its intentional; its trying to edit the `<p>` tag that you put in, and its basically generating HTML after that.

Comment: What do all those occurences of *it's* refer to?